# Applications of signed permutations to machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, permutations

Are there some applications of signed permutations to machine learning? I searched on google and only found one [paper](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~reltech/PFG/2017/PFG-17-03.pdf). Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you expect such applications?

Comment: The paper you cite has an application going in the other direction – machine learning is applied to the study of permutations.